# How to aceess linked api security code using server to server call in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, linkedin-api

I am using Ruby on Rails(3.2.3) and omniauth/linkedin gems

I have authorized my web application from the user . After granting access linked redirect user to a page with security code like given below

---

You have successfully authorized emprat
Please return to your application and enter the following security code to grant access:

45656

---

I don't want that user have to copy and paste this code. There is a close button which bring me to the callback url but doesn't have any parameters.

How can I access this code with server - to- server call.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is once you have the PIN verifier, save that in a session variable or somewhere in memory. Take that PIN and use it to upgrade for the user's access token. Here's an example of how to do this using the OAuth gem in Rails:

```
@access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => verifier)
```

All you need to do is pass the "verifier" to retrieve the access token. So, this can all be done programmatically without the user needing to copy/paste the code themselves. Just save the PIN verifier in memory and use it.